# How do I add a discount code to my cart and send it to paypal checkout?

Tags: paypal, bigcartel

I'm trying to add a discount code field to my website in big cartel. I've set the available discount codes in bigcartel, but no discount field is shown when checking out. This is because I send users to PayPal to checkout. Is there a way to add a field for the discount code in my cart, then send that discount to paypal on checkout?

What I really need is an example of how to make an `<input/>` for the discount code such that it gets processed on form submission. I'm new to big cartel, and as far as I can tell I don't have the ability to change the code for how the cart form is processed.

I've been digging through bigcartel and PayPal's docs for a while now with no luck, and am hoping someone on here knows the solution, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a discount field to the Cart page by using `discount_code_input`:

```
Enter discount: {{ cart.discount | discount_code_input }}
```

This is also documented here: https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#discountcodeinputdiscount-id-classname

Additionally there's a number of different variables used to check whether discounts are enabled, the amount, the code that was entered, etc: https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#variables-1

And finally, every Big Cartel theme is on GitHub, so you can download the theme code, run it locally with Dugway, and get a better idea of how our themes work. Here's Lunch Break for example: https://github.com/bigcartel-themes/lunch-break/blob/master/source/cart.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking how to mimic how Big Cartel themes accomplish this, but in my custom theme.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get some time